# Using Iron-Ajax with XML?

Tags: xml, polymer-1.0

I can't get the Iron-Ajax element working with XML. It errors out about content origin.

```
  <iron-ajax auto
      url="http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=agencyList"
      handle-as="xml"
      last-response="{{agencies}}"></iron-ajax>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xml response available in `{{agencies}}` but you have to parse it.
Here is an example shows the no. of `<agency>` tags in the response using `on-response` event.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

  <title>Iron-ajax</title>
  
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/master/webcomponents.js"></script>
  
  <base href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.0.1/lib/">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">  
  
  
  
  <!--<link rel="import" href="all-elements.html">-->
  
</head>
<body class="fullbleed">

<test-elem></test-elem>

<dom-module id="test-elem">
  <template>
   <iron-ajax auto
                  url='http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=agencyList'
                  handle-as="xml"
                  on-response="_on_response"
                  last-response="{{agencies}}"></iron-ajax>

  </template>
              
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is : "test-elem",
      _on_response : function(r){
        response = r.detail.response;
        list = response.querySelectorAll('agency');
        
        console.log(list.length);
        alert(list.length + " Agency");
        //alert(r.detail.response);
        
      }
      });
    </script>
    
</dom-module>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if I want to display with 'dom-repeat' items="{{ agencies}}" ?

Comment: I found it! `<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{ nodeList(xmldata, 'agency') }}"> `and `nodeList return element ? Array.prototype.slice.call(element.querySelectorAll(name)) : []`